# Python Sleep Function Issue

Tags: python

Running this code the `time.sleep()` function is executed before the other instructions are ended. Can you tell me why?

```
def stopClient(self):

    os.system("taskkill /F /IM Client.exe")

    self.log_textbox.configure(state="normal")
    self.log_textbox.insert(tk.END, "\n" + self.getTime() + " [Client]" + " Shutted Down.")
    self.log_textbox.configure(state="disabled")
    time.sleep(3)
    self.quit()
```

Comment: What makes you think that is true?

Comment: @chepner because the program becomes frozen before the text appears on the textbox.. And when the sleep is over, the program quits as self.quit() says...

Comment: maybe log_textbox only works after program ends?

Comment: @Serge nope, because i've used it before and all works perfectly..